# itextsharp how to add a full line break

Tags: c#, itext

I use itextsharp and i need to draw a dotted linebreak from left to right of the page(100% width) but don't know how. The doc always has a margin left right. Please help [image]

```
var pageSize = PageSize.A4;

        if (_pdfSettings.LetterPageSizeEnabled)
        {
            pageSize = PageSize.LETTER;
        }


        var doc = new Document(pageSize);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream);
        doc.Open();

        //fonts

        var titleFont = GetFont();
        titleFont.SetStyle(Font.BOLD);
        titleFont.Color = BaseColor.BLACK;
        titleFont.Size = 16;

        var largeFont = GetFont();
        largeFont.SetStyle(Font.BOLD);
        largeFont.Color = BaseColor.BLACK;
        largeFont.Size = 18;

        int ordCount = orders.Count;
        int ordNum = 0;

        foreach (var order in orders)
        {

            var addressTable = new PdfPTable(3);
            addressTable.WidthPercentage = 100f;
            addressTable.SetWidths(new[] { 25, 37, 37 });


            // sender address

            cell = new PdfPCell();
            //cell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            cell.AddElement(new Paragraph("Người Gửi", titleFont));
            cell.AddElement(new Paragraph(_localizationService.GetResource("admin.orders.pdfinvoice.sender", lang.Id), smallFont));
            cell.AddElement(new Paragraph(_localizationService.GetResource("admin.orders.pdfinvoice.senderaddress", lang.Id), smallFont));
            cell.AddElement(new Paragraph(_localizationService.GetResource("PDFInvoice.Hotline", lang.Id), smallFont));
            cell.AddElement(new Paragraph("TAKARA.VN", largeFont));

            addressTable.AddCell(cell);

            ......
           Chunk linebreak = new Chunk(new DottedLineSeparator());
                doc.Add(linebreak);   

                doc.Add(new Paragraph(""));
           ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the example [FullDottedLine](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/FullDottedLine).

You're creating a `DottedLineSeparator` of which the width percentage is 100% by default. This 100% is the full available width *withing the margins of the page*. If you want the line to exceed the available width, you need a percentage that is higher than 100%.

In the example, the default page size (A4) and the default margins (36) are used. This means that the width of the page is 595 user units and the available width equals 595 - (2 x 36) user units. The percentage needed to span the complete width of the page equals 100 x (595 / 523).

Take a look at the resulting PDF file [full_dotted_line.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/full_dotted_line.pdf) and you'll see that the line now runs through the margins.

Comment: thanks for your help. however somehow my itextsharp for .net doesn't have  setPercentage method.

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: Bruno's example is Java. Whenever you see a Java example you can almost always assume that the `getXYZ`/`setXXX` methods were converted to `XYZ` properties in .Net. So instead of `setPercentage(X)` you'd use `Percentage = X`.

Comment: The link you provided doesn't work anymore.